# sh: 0: Can't open in jenkin execute shell

Tags: shell

I am running shell script from Execute Shell in Jenkin and getting the below error in console :

**Error :**

`sh: 0: Can't open /home/selvan/mytool/start_test.sh`

I gave the following command to give jenkin user permission but still not working :

`sudo chown tomcat8:jenkins /home/selvan/mytool/start_test.sh
sudo chown tomcat8:jenkins /home/selvan/mytool/`

**Current permission :**

`ls -altrh /home/selvan/mytool/start_test.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat8 jenkins 457 Sep 27 21:11 /home/selvan/mytool/start_test.sh`

Any pointer to solve andrun the script form jenkin machine please ?

Thanks ,
Mselvan

Comment: Considering sharing the first few lines of start_test.sh, and the parametrs t the Jenks Execute Shell ?

Comment: Also, is you Jenkins running over multiple machines ? Can each machine access the named folder ?

Comment: Is `tomcat8` a user belonging to `jenkins` group or vice versa? Shouldn’t the file ownership read `jenkins:tomcat8`  instead?

Comment: Thanks Dibakar , your suggestion worked but may i know how you figured out the root cause